# Remove the inferior digits of a number

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Given a number *n* of *x* digits. How to remove *y* digits in a way the remaining digits results in the greater possible number?

Examples:

```
1)x=7  y=3
n=7816295
  -8-6-95
         =8695

2)x=4  y=2
n=4213
  4--3
      =43

3)x=3  y=1
n=888
     =88
```

Just to state: *x > y > 0*.

Comment: Where's your process of thought just now? Try thinking _Which x-y digits do I keep?_ (Or even: How do I find the same question on stackoverflow, if worded differently? Looking at the "Related" column to the right _might_ be cheating.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each digit to remove: iterate through the digits left to right; if you find a digit that's less than the one to its right, remove it and stop, otherwise remove the last digit.

If the number of digits `x` is greater than the actual length of the number, it means there are leading zeros. Since those will be the first to go, you can simply reduce the count `y` by a corresponding amount.

Here's a working version in Python:

```
def remove_digits(n, x, y):
    s = str(n)
    if len(s) > x:
        raise ValueError
    elif len(s) < x:
        y -= x - len(s)
    if y <= 0:
        return n
    for r in range(y):
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if s[i] < s[i+1:i+2]:
                break
        s = s[:i] + s[i+1:]
    return int(s)

>>> remove_digits(7816295, 7, 3)
8695
>>> remove_digits(4213, 4, 2)
43
>>> remove_digits(888, 3, 1)
88
```

I hesitated to submit this, because it seems too simple. But I wasn't able to think of a case where it wouldn't work.

Comment: You made it easy, I can't believe it was simple this way.. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

if x = y we have to remove all the digits.

Otherwise, you need to find maximum digit in first y + 1 digits. Then remove all the y0 elements before this maximum digit. Then you need to add that maximum to the answer and  then repeat that task again, but you need now to remove y - y0 elements now.

Straight forward implementation will work in O(x^2) time in the worst case.

But finding maximum in the given range can be done effectively using Segment Tree data structure. Time complexity will be O(x * log(x)) in the worst case.

P. S. I just realized, that it possible to solve in O(x) also, using the fact, that exists only 10 digits (but the algorithm maybe a little bit complicated). We need to find the minimum in the given range [L, R], but the ranges in this task will "change" from left to the right (L and R always increase). And we just need to store 10 pointers to the digits (1 per digit) to the first position in the number such that position >= L. Then to find the minimum, we need to check only 10 pointers. To update the pointers, we will try to move them right.

So the time complexity will be O(10 * x) = O(x)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an O(x) solution. It builds an index that maps (i, d) to j, the smallest number > i such that the j'th digit of n is d. With this index, one can easily find the largest possible next digit in the solution in O(1) time.

```
def index(digits):
    next = [len(digits)+1] * 10
    for i in xrange(len(digits), 0, -1):
        next[ord(digits[i-1])-ord('0')] = i-1
        yield next[::-1]

def minseq(n, y):
    n = str(n)
    idx = list(index(n))[::-1]
    i, r = 0, []
    for ry in xrange(len(n)-y):
        i = next(j for j in idx[i] if j <= y+ry) + 1
        r.append(n[i - 1])
    return ''.join(r)

print minseq(7816295, 3)
print minseq(4213, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pseudocode:

```
Number.toDigits().filter (sortedSet (Number.toDigits()). take (y))
```

Imho you don't need to know x.

For efficiency, Number.toDigits () could be precalculated

```
digits = Number.toDigits()
digits.filter (sortedSet (digits).take (y))
```

Depending on language and context, you either output the digits and are done or have to convert the result into a number again.

Working Scala-Code for example:

```
def toDigits (l: Long) : List [Long] = if (l < 10) l :: Nil else (toDigits (l /10)) :+ (l % 10)

val num = 734529L
val dig = toDigits (num)
dig.filter (_ > ((dig.sorted).take(2).last))
```

A sorted set is a set which is sorted, which means, every element is only contained once and then the resulting collection is sorted by some criteria, for example numerical ascending. => 234579.

We take two of them (23) and from that subset the last (3) and filter the number by the criteria, that the digits have to be greater than that value (3).

Your question does not explicitly say, that each digit is only contained once in the original number, but since you didn't give a criterion, which one to remove in doubt, I took it as an implicit assumption.

Other languages may of course have other expressions (x.sorted, x.toSortedSet, new SortedSet (num), ...) or lack certain classes, functions, which you would have to build on your own.

You might need to write your own filter method, which takes a pedicate P, and a collection C, and returns a new collection of all elements which satisfy P, P being a Method which takes one T and returns a Boolean. Very useful stuff.

Comment: What does it mean to filter a sequence by a sorted set? What _is_ a sorted set?

Comment: @PaulHankin: Wrote explanation into answer, + working code example (Scala)

Comment: The problem's easier if you assume there's only one of each digit. But I think you've got the germ of a solution to the full problem: if you count the occurrences of each digit, you can figure out which digits appear in the solution. (For example, if there's 5 9's and 4 8's and 3 7's, and you want 10 digit, you know the answer's going to have 5 9's, 4 8's and 1 7). You still have to get the digits in the right order though (eg: pick 3 digits from 8998).